# Google map API Error-Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When setting the maxZoom:18 
I am getting error in my console

```
js:101 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Py._.k.get (js:101)
    at ly._.k.get (js:101)
    at my (map.js:12)
    at ly._.k.zoom_changed (map.js:40)
    at Hb (js:38)
    at ly._.k.set (js:101)
    at my (map.js:12)
    at ly._.k.zoom_changed (map.js:40)
    at Hb (js:38)
    at ly._.k.set (js:101)
```

Here is my js code ..

```
$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       maxZoom: 12,
       center: { lat: parseFloat(Center_lat) , lng: parseFloat(center_lang) },
    // center: { lat: 22.08672 , lng: 79.42444 }
       mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
       }
  });
```

please help me out. Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Check if center_lat and center_lng are string values.

Comment: I tried by passing                                                                                                           center: { lat: 22.08672 , lng: 79.42444 }                                                                     But still getting the same error

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom


Read this documention . It stats here you need to check maximum available zoom at given lat lng. 18 May not be valid for this location .

Comment: If I set maxZoom:0 its still giving the same error.

Comment: Would you mind creating a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

The cause for the error in my map was that an invalid latitude and/or longitude was being used when creating a polyline like so:

```
var polylineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),  
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),  
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431.1156),  
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)  
];  

var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({  
    path: polylineCoordinates,    
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,  
    strokeWeight: 2,  
    map: map  
});
```

Take a look at the above code. Can you see that one of the longitudes, ‘178.431.1156‘, being used isn’t valid? After fixing this and making it a valid set of co-ordinates, the polyline should then begin to appear.